# Implementing Transaction or Saga with GraphQL using Hasura Client

Tags: graphql, transactions, microservices, hasura, saga

I am working on a project where I need to execute multiple GraphQL mutations in a single transaction using the Hasura client. I'm also interested in a saga transaction implementation if possible. However, I am having trouble achieving this and would appreciate some guidance or best practices suggestions.

Let me give a bit more context with a simple scenario. Consider the following GraphQL mutation:

```
mutation reset_author {
  delete_article (
    where: {author_id: {_eq: 6}}
  ) {
    affected_rows
  }
  update_author (
    where: {id: {_eq: 6}} _set: {name: "Cory"}
  ) {
    returning {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

In this mutation, I'm first deleting all articles associated with a specific author (author_id: 6), then I'm updating the name of the author to "Cory".

I'd like to know if there is a way to use the affected_rows result from the delete_article mutation as part of the where or _set conditions in the update_author mutation that follows? Based on my research, this doesn't seem to be directly supported, but perhaps there's a workaround?

Additionally, I'm wondering how I could wrap these two mutations into a single transaction, ensuring that either both succeed or both fail. In essence, what I'm looking for is an approach to create a saga transaction using GraphQL and Hasura.

Any guidance or direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you can do this "indirectly" by defining a custom function in Postgres and adding that to GraphQL: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/custom-functions/

If there is a concern with creating DDLs for this, then the new Native Queries feature can also help you do a similar thing but without creating a database object: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/logical-models/native-queries/ but I think mutations support is still pending here.